# Breadboard Layout Validation

Tags: circuit-design, rectifier, layout, breadboard

I have a breadboard with a bridge rectifier circuit that I am hoping to have someone validate for me.

The circuit with breadboard pins is:
[image]

And a picture of my breadboard is:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If that's ac mains. Running ac mains through a breadboard is a very bad and dangerous idea.

Comment: How many pF in that ceramic there? And I completely agree with @VoltageSpike with respect to *"I hope this isn't mains-connected"*! You are using a low AC voltage through a transformer, right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct, but it will be much easier to verify and less error-prone if you use <+> and <-> lines properly. It will be easier to plug diodes and capacitor directly into these lines.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to take a look.